# How to invoke System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<> on IEnumerable<T> using Reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, collections, ienumerable

I have a bunch of IEnumerable Collections which exact number and types is subject of frequent changes (due to automatic code generation).

It looks something like this:

```
public class MyCollections {
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SomeType> SomeTypeCollection;
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<OtherType> OtherTypeCollection;
    ...
```

At runtime i want to determine each Type and it's count without having to rewrite the code after every code generation. So i am looking for a generic approach using reflection. The result i am looking for is something like:

```
MyType: 23
OtherType: 42
```

My problem is that i can't figure how to invoke the Count method properly. Here is what i have so far:

```
        // Handle to the Count method of System.Linq.Enumerable
        MethodInfo countMethodInfo = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethod("Count", new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>) });

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyCollections).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            if (propertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                Type genericType = propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genericType == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                {
                    // access the collection property
                    object collection = property.GetValue(someInstanceOfMyCollections, null);

                    // access the type of the generic collection
                    Type genericArgument = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                    // make a generic method call for System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<> for the type of this collection
                    MethodInfo localCountMethodInfo = countMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);

                    // invoke Count method (this fails)
                    object count = localCountMethodInfo.Invoke(collection, null);

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", genericArgument.Name, count);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is "MyCollections" a type of a variable/field/property? You seem to be using it as both.

Comment: Your count MethodInfo-reference is null. Fix that and the code would probably work.

Comment: Sorry, the given example is not accurate. I have fixed it.

Comment: What I wouldn't give for generic wildcards in .NET . . .

Comment: Before I read the answers, can anyone explain this question to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insist on doing it the hard way ;p

Changes:

- how you obtain countMethodInfo for a generic method
- the arguments to Invoke

Code (note `obj` is my instance of `MyCollections`):

```
    MethodInfo countMethodInfo = typeof (System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(
        method => method.Name == "Count" && method.IsStatic && method.GetParameters().Length == 1);

    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyCollections).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
        if (propertyType.IsGenericType)
        {
            Type genericType = propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            if (genericType == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            {
                // access the collection property
                object collection = property.GetValue(obj, null);

                // access the type of the generic collection
                Type genericArgument = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                // make a generic method call for System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<> for the type of this collection
                MethodInfo localCountMethodInfo = countMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);

                // invoke Count method (this fails)
                object count = localCountMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] {collection});

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", genericArgument.Name, count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After examining your response i suddently understood my mistake. In fact only the arguments to Invoke had to be adjusted (of course!) and then all of my original implementation worked as expected.
Even tough your Linq approach to retrieving countMethodInfo looks sexy it feels a bit to complcated for me ;-)

Answer (score 3):

That is going to involve some `MakeGenericMethod` - and a lot of reflection *generally*. Personally, I would be tempted to just simplify by ditching the generics in this case:

```
public static int Count(IEnumerable data) {
    ICollection list = data as ICollection;
    if(list != null) return list.Count;
    int count = 0;
    IEnumerator iter = data.GetEnumerator();
    using(iter as IDisposable) {
        while(iter.MoveNext()) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You can cast to the non-generic `IEnumerable` trivially, even if fetching via reflection.

Comment: Of course, this is a nice idea. But i am looking for the solution to my flaw in MakeGenericMethod.

Comment: Can't we just `foreach` over `data`, or do we need to deal with the enumerator explicitly?

Comment: Why are some many people 'afraid' to lose generics by casting to `IList` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @AakashM, Marc, approach avoids needless calls to `Current` that might (depending on enumerator) be expensive and might not be optimised away.

@Marc, I'd do the first test as a test for ICollection, rather than IList, as ICollection is where the Count property is defined for IList, and this way you'll catch other collection types with a built-in (and likely more efficient) Count.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: If `Current` is expensive, you are doing it wrong  :)

Comment: @AakashM - probably, but simply: we don't need that data. `foreach` would be simpler, of course.

Comment: @leppie. Yes, but who's to say the person (may not be you) didn't do it wrong! If they are converting from another source then you might do that on Current rather than on MoveNext. Unlikely to be unbelievably expensive, but possibly non-trivial, and not the worse approach in the world (not how I'd do it, but meh).

Comment: @Jon Hanna: `MoveNext` generally sets up the current value as it has to return a boolean to specify whether it was found or not.

Comment: @leppie. Yes, it generally does, though it could go no further than (say) calling Read() on a DataReader.

Answer (score 2):

*By now, the question has been answered, but I'd like to present you a trimmed down — and I think, rather trivial version — of the "calling a generic extension method", which can be used to invoke `Count` reflectively:*

```
// get Enumerable (which holds the extension methods)
Type enumerableT = typeof(Enumerable);

// get the Count-method (there are only two, you can check the parameter-count as in above 
// to be certain. Here we know it's the first, so I use the first:
MemberInfo member = enumerableT.GetMember("Count")[0];

// create the generic method (instead of int, replace with typeof(yourtype) in your code)
MethodInfo method = ((MethodInfo) member).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

// invoke now becomes trivial
int count = (int)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { yourcollection });
```

The above works, because you don't need to use the generic type of `IEnumerable<>` to be able to invoke `Count`, which is an extension of `Enumerable` and takes an argument of `IEnumerable<T>` as first param (it's an extension), but you don't need to specify that.

Note that, from the reading of your question, it seems to me that you should actually use generics for your types, which adds type safety back into your project and still allows you to use Count or whatever. After all, the one thing that's certain is that all are `Enumerable`, right? If so, who needs reflection?

Comment: The reason for reflection is simple: what you label as "yourtype" is not known at compile time (or at least it changes frequently).

Comment: @embee: that, I understood. But if it changes frequently (it is generated) it is ideal for generics. But in all honesty, I do not know enough of your situation to know for certain whether your approach is a good one considering.

Comment: Probably i just dont understand generics enough to follow your suggestion, sorry. In this scenario MyCollections is something that you must take for granted.

Comment: @embee: I added a note, hope it clarifies it a bit. It is my understanding that you are currently doing more than is necessary to invoke a static method with a collection of a type of which you do not know the type at compile time. But maybe I've just utterly misunderstood? :)

Comment: On new reading, I see that I follow quite closely what's already been said. I was distracted by your foreach-loop. Sorry. So, the above should read: this is all it takes for calling generic method `Count`. Your loop is part of your base logics.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(theCollection);
```

Edit: you say it's generated though, so can you not just generate a properties with calls to `Count()`?

```
public class MyCollections
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SomeType> SomeTypeCollection;
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<OtherType> OtherTypeCollection;

    public int CountSomeTypeCollection
    {
        get { return this.SomeTypeCollection.Count(); }
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the fact that you don't know `T` at compile-time.

Comment: MyCollections is generated automaticly and overwritten quite often. This is why i have to use reflection from the outside. I know it's tricky but it should be possible...